# F#: CSV cleaning

Tags: csv, f#, data-cleaning, f#-data

I'm trying using F# to clean a CSV dataset. For example I want to change string values in one column to lower case. I don't know if it's better to work with loaded data as CsvProvider Rows or I should create some struct and convert these Rows to struct list. Either way, how can I load CSV, modify values in one column and save the modified dataset to CSV again?

I've been searching the FSharp.Data documentation and other pages and I didn't find any relevant examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSV type provider is great for reading CSV data, but it is less easy to use for data cleaning and transformations. For this, I'd recommend using the [Deedle data exploration library](https://fslab.org/Deedle/) instead. With Deedle, you can do this easily:

```
#r "nuget:Deedle"
open Deedle

let df = Frame.ReadCsv(@"C:\Temp\titanic.csv")
let newName = 
  df.GetColumn<string>("Name") 
  |> Series.mapValues (fun s -> s.ToLower())
df.ReplaceColumn("Name", newName)
df.SaveCsv(@"C:\Temp\titanic.csv")
```